# List all public class properties and fields at design time in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ide, code-generation

Is it possible to get a list of all public members of a type in the Visual Studio IDE?

When writing tests I often need to set all public fields/setters in a class/struct to some value.

The best thing would be if I could type:

```
MyType x = new MyType();
```

and then autogenerate something like

```
x.StrProp = "StrProp";
x.IntProp = 0;
x.DtProp = DateTime.Now;
x.OtherProp = new Othertype()
```

But just getting a list and then use column editing would help a lot

**Edit:**
Found out that it wasn't very difficult to do with a macro

Answer (score 1):

What about starting a debug session, breaking at the beginning, and then calling something like

```
typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Control)
    .GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
```

in the immediate window? :)

The result is something like this:

```
{System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[0x0000004a]}
    [0x00000000]: {System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleObject AccessibilityObject}
    [0x00000001]: {System.String AccessibleDefaultActionDescription}
    [0x00000002]: {System.String AccessibleDescription}
    [0x00000003]: {System.String AccessibleName}
    [0x00000004]: {System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleRole AccessibleRole}
    [0x00000005]: {Boolean AllowDrop}
```

Unfortunately, you can't use lambda expressions in the immediate window - this would make it easy to get the properties in a format easier for you. But then, I'd suggest writing a really simple tool that loads your assembly, lets you select the type and just outputs the code in the desired format (and/or copies it into the clipboard or into the VS editor). This tool will at least do exactly what you need. Then configure the tool e.g. as an external tool in Visual Studio, to make it easier to run with the current project.